# How to Change a value in a Dataframe based on a lookup from a json file

Tags: json, pandas, dataframe

I want to practice building models and I figured that I'd do it with something that I am familiar with: League of Legends. I'm having trouble replacing an integer in a dataframe with a value in a json.

The datasets I'm using come off of the kaggle. You can grab it and run it for yourself.

https://www.kaggle.com/datasnaek/league-of-legends

I have json file of the form: (it's actually must bigger, but I shortened it)

```
   {
    "type": "champion",
    "version": "7.17.2",
    "data": {
        "1": {
            "title": "the Dark Child",
            "id": 1,
            "key": "Annie",
            "name": "Annie"
        },
        "2": {
            "title": "the Berserker",
            "id": 2,
            "key": "Olaf",
            "name": "Olaf"
        }
      }
    }
```

and dataframe of the form

print df

```
     gameDuration  t1_champ1id
0              1949            1
1              1851            2
2              1493            1
3              1758            1
4              2094            2
```

I want to replace the ID in t1_champ1id with the lookup value in the json.

If both of these were dataframe, then I could use the merge option.

This is what I've tried. I don't know if this is the best way to read in the json file.

```
import pandas
df = pandas.read_csv("lol_file.csv",header=0)
champ = pandas.read_json("champion_info.json", typ='series')


for i in champ.data[0]:
    for j in df:
        if df.loc[j,('t1_champ1id')] == i:
            df.loc[j,('t1_champ1id')] = champ[0][i]['name']
```

I get the below error:

> the label [gameDuration] is not in the [index]'

I'm not sure that this is the most efficient way to do this, but I'm not sure how to do it at all either.

What do y'all think?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`for j in df:` iterates over the column names in `df`, which is unnecessary, since you're only looking to match against the column `'t1_champ1id'`. A better use of pandas functionality is to condense the id:name pairs from your JSON file into a dictionary, and then map it to `df['t1_champ1id']`.

```
player_names = {v['id']:v['name'] for v in json_file['data'].itervalues()}

df.loc[:, 't1_champ1id'] = df['t1_champ1id'].map(player_names)
#        gameDuration t1_champ1id
# 0          1949       Annie
# 1          1851        Olaf
# 2          1493       Annie
# 3          1758       Annie
# 4          2094        Olaf
```

Comment: I knew that you could do something slick like this, but I had no idea how. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Created a dataframe from the 'data' in the json file (also transposed the resulting dataframe and then set the index to what you want to map, the id)  then mapped that to the original df.

```
import json

with open('champion_info.json') as data_file:    
   champ_json = json.load(data_file)

champs = pd.DataFrame(champ_json['data']).T



champs.set_index('id',inplace=True)

df['champ_name'] = df.t1_champ1id.map(champs['name'])
```

Comment: When I run 'champion_info.json', I get a 

'str' object has no attribute 'read' error message. Do you know why this is?

I can run pandas.read_json('champion_info.json'), just fine though. I also ran the json against https://jsonlint.com/ and it is 'valid'.

Comment: my apologies, see updated solution. You must first open the json file, and then use the json load command